# Tetrahedron VABC. Find the length of BC.

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus

[image]

[image]

My attempt, by using sine rules,

I found that $VB=22.64495898$, $AB=19.20401435$, $VC=16.28636966$ and $AC=4.930639115$. And by cosine rules, I found $BC=16.86$. But the given answer is $21.54$. But not sure why. Hope anyone can help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you detail your approach so we can help see where you went wrong?

Comment: Yeap. Sure thing. @OlympusHero

Comment: Find a formula {online} for the altitude of "any" triangle and apply it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\triangle VAC$  is a perpendicular triangle.

$$\frac{12}{AC}=\tan 25^\circ$$

$$AC \approx 25.73$$

\begin{align}
BC &= \sqrt{AB^2+AC^2 - 2 AB \cdot AC \cos 55^\circ} \\
&\approx\sqrt{19.2^2+25.73^2 - 2 (19.2) (25.73) \cos 55^\circ}\\
&\approx 21.54
\end{align}